# Polymer - ready event but bounded data not ready

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In the todo-list app from [PolymerLabs](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/todo-list) , I added a `ready()` function in todo-data.html as follows:

```
<dom-module id="todo-data">

  <template>

  <style>

  </style>

  <firebase-collection location="{{userLocation}}"
                     data="{{fbTodos}}"
                     on-firebase-value="_firebaseLoaded">
  </firebase-collection>

  .....
</template>
<script>
  Polymer({

    is: 'todo-data',

  properties: {

    todos: {
      notify: true
    },

    user: {
      observer: '_userChanged'
    },

   .......

    ready: function() {
      console.log(this.user);
  }

});
```

The `user` attribute value is bounded to it from index.html as follows:

```
//index.html 
<template is="dom-bind" id="app">

<todo-auth id="auth"
           user="{{user}}"
           location="[[firebaseURL]]"
           user="{{user}}">
</todo-auth>

<todo-data location="[[firebaseURL]]"
           todos="{{todos}}"
           user="{{user}}">
</todo-data>
..........
```

May I know why user is always printed out as `undefined` in `ready()`? It seems that when `ready()` is called, the bounded data is not yet populated with the correct data. When can i reliably know when a bounded data has been initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ready()` is called this only means that Polymer is done creating and initializing the elements. The call to Firebase is only just invoked at that time and Polymer doesn't wait for the call to the Firebase server to respond. This is done by code in `<firebase-collection>` Polymer is not aware of.

When data arrives from the server it is passed to `fbTodos`

Create a property `fbTodos` and and observer that is executed when `fbTodos` changes. This observer will be called when the data arrive.

properties: {

```
fbTodos: {
  observer: '_dataArrvied'
},

user: {
  observer: '_userChanged'
},
```

The `<firebase-collection>` element doesn't provide an `firebase-value` event therefore

```
on-firebase-value="_firebaseLoaded"
```

seems redundant.

I haven't used this element myself yet.

Comment: Thanks. I realised that the firebase-value event is fired somehow. It may be from a nested element. :)